# How do I improve the efficiency of my function?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

So I wrote this small python program that creates anagrams from inputted letters and language, but it crashes as soon as the entered word has too many possible outputs or simply too long. How can I improve my code so that it becomes more performant/efficient?

```
def createAnagrams(word, language):
    dictLanguage = enchant.Dict(language) #library that can check if word exists 
    existingWords = [] 

    for i in range(1, len(word)+1):
        for j in permutations(word, i):
            existingWords.append("".join(j))
    existingWords = set(existingWords) #remove duplicates
    existingWords = list(existingWords) #change back to list to be able to iterate through it
    for k in range(len(existingWords)):
        if(dictLanguage.check(existingWords[k])) and (len(existingWords[k])>1): #if word exists and longer than 1 char print it
            print(existingWords[k])
```

Works for words like "hello", "patrick", "yesterday" but crashes for words like "announcements", "subscriptions". Would like to have the expected output for longer words.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are essentially asking two questions here, 1) how to fix it and 2) how to make it faster, the latter of which should be posted on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I thought about that but what I essentially want to know is how to fix it, since that is most likely achieved through improvement it probably fits on CodeReview as well as it does here. Will give it a go on CodeReview too tho thanks.

Comment: Beware that you should only post *working* code on CodeReview. Besides that, what does `permutations` do, and what is the format of `enchant.Dict`? Also note that `set` itself is iterable so conversion back into `list` is unnecessary.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Does this count as working? Since it works for small-medium sized words but only crashes for longer ones. Permutations gives me the possibility of looping more efficiently through my letters to create every possible letter combination. What do you mean by "format of enchant.Dict"? I will have to look at set again then thanks.

Comment: "Working" means returning the correct result for **all** valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason for your program crashing is some kind of out of memory error. Specifically, you create a list containing all permutations of all substrings of "announcements" (6749977113 many). This is not really a good idea...

I would suggest implementing a trie for the `language` and performing a tree search based on the letters in the given word in order to obtain all language words contained in the `word` in order to get the list of substrings. Combining them into a complete anagram is a different question of course.